# Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job. Finished: FAILURE

Tags: java, git, jenkins, build

I got the following error while building a java project with jenkins which source code is on Github.

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\Administrator\.jenkins\workspace\TestProject
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy.git
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.username testuser # timeout=10
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.57_test\temp\git2715746879795272610.credentials\" # timeout=10
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/xxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy/*
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/master/TestProjectSearch^{commit}" # timeout=10
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "refs/remotes/origin/origin/master/TestProjectSearch^{commit}" # timeout=10
  > C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe rev-parse "origin/master/TestProjectSearch^{commit}" # timeout=10
  ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.
  Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you asked about this in June, 2016, it was likely due to this [security update from May, 2016](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+SECURITY-170) which broke the Github Pull Request builder plugin. According to that page, the functionality was later restored.

Jenkins users who were behind on updating their Jenkins installs or plugins may have experienced the issue at a later date.